# Getting QuotaExceededError

Tags: angular

I am retrieving data from SQL Server through C# code as the data which I am trying to retrieve has 17000 rows I am getting QuotaExceededError for a particular case while for other case the number of rows are less so I am getting data for that but error for large data. What should I do to solve this error. For front end using Angular 6.

Comment: are you sure this is on retrieving data from the server and not on storing that data on  `localstorage`?

Answer (score 0):

You cant resolve it using angular.But you can implement either

- pagination and show data in list and then let user navigate it by pages.
- Adapt something like
  this:https://medium.com/@nisalperi/how-i-solved-the-localstorage-quotaexceedederror-dom-exception-22-b69db46f0cee